# How do I render a SHtml.ajaxButton with 'onClick' action and href link in a Lift Snippet

Tags: scala, render, lift, shtml

I'm trying to render an ajaxButton in Lift that, once clicked, updates a SessionVar and then goes to another page using href:

```
def render ={
"li *" #> userItems.map(item =>
  "li.button_open" #> SHtml.ajaxButton("Open", () => ajaxButtonOpen(item),
            "class" -> "btn btn-primary", "href" -> {Site.menuItem.url})
    )
}

def ajaxButtonOpen(item:Item) : JsCmd = {
   UsersCurrentItemId apply item._id
   JsCmd.unitToJsCmd(Unit)
}
```

This code will execute ajaxButtonOpen but will not go to the Site.menuItem. I've tried other alternatives such as:

```
"li.button_test" #>  <a class="btn btn-primary" href= {Site.menuItem.url} onClick="{ajaxButtonOpen(item)}"> "Open"</a>
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def render ={
"li *" #> userItems.map(item =>
  "li.button_open" #> SHtml.ajaxButton("Open", () => ajaxButtonOpen(item),
       "class" -> "btn btn-primary")
    )
}

def ajaxButtonOpen(item:Item) : JsCmd = {
   UsersCurrentItemId apply item._id
   JsCmds.RedirectTo(Site.menuItem.url)
}
```

I replaced the `Noop` return from your method with a `RedirectTo`. The [`JsCmds.RedirectTo`](http://liftweb.net/api/25-M4/api/scala/#net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds%24%24RedirectTo) will issue a javascript redirect to the new page and should accomplish what you are looking for.

Alternately, you could use your original `ajaxButtonOpen` function with [`SHtml.onEvent`](http://liftweb.net/api/25-M4/api/scala/#net.liftweb.http.SHtml) to add the ajax event handler to your link:

```
"li.button_test" #> 
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href={Site.menuItem.url} onClick={
    SHtml.onEvent( e => ajaxButtonOpen(item))
  } />
```